# MvxImageView.SetImageBitmap causing "Memory violation"

Tags: xamarin.android, android-imageview, mvvmcross

I have built an app in iOS and now building the app in Android.  I'm basically done with the app but I'm running into a pretty consistent problem in the app.  I will be going through the app hitting various pages when the app crashes.  It seems to be pretty random and appears to be a memory issue.  Each "page" has maybe 0-2 images on the page, but nothing major (small png files).  I'm using a combination of android ImageView and MvxImageView.  I'm setting the MvxImageView through binding ImageUrl like this:

local:MvxBind="ImageUrl CurrencyImage"

Here is the exception I get:

```
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_void_method_a (intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) <0x0005b>
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment/InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference,Java.Interop.JniObjectReference,Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12079
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers/JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (string,Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) [0x00068] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:31
[mono-rt]   at Android.Widget.ImageView.SetImageBitmap (Android.Graphics.Bitmap) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Android.Widget.ImageView.cs:1026
[mono-rt]   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxImageView.SetImageBitmap (Android.Graphics.Bitmap) <IL 0x00032, 0x0019b>
[mono-rt]   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxImageView/<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<ImageHelperOnImageChanged>b__0 () <IL 0x00011, 0x000b7>
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.037ff22d-dd39-45fa-8726-c673a7d6897c (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.037ff22d-dd39-45fa-8726-c673a7d6897c (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00021, 0x000ef>
```

And here is the audit I see in DDMS:

```
10-13 17:26:06.213: E/audit(2793): type=1701 msg=audit(1476393966.213:869): auid=4294967295 uid=10198 gid=10198 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=14236 comm="APPNAME.droid" reason="memory violation" sig=11
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  When I say consistent above, basically within 30 seconds of "hammering" around in the app something happens.

Devices: Most of testing on Samsung Galaxy Tab A and that's from exception above.  Also have tested on older LG phone and latest Nexus.  LG phone gets same error.  Latest Nexus I have gotten the error but not as consistent.  I can be on the app for a while sometimes with no issues.

Comment: Are you using the `MvvmCross DownloadCache` and `File` plugin? These can be found on `NuGet`.

Comment: Yes I'm using both plugins.

Comment: Can you make a repro sample and submit a bug on https://github.com/mvvmcros/mvvmcross-plugins/issues ? Alternatively you can try using something like FFImageLoading instead and see if this persists. FFImageLoading has a MvvmCross specific ImageView which you can bind to similarly as MvxImageView.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back.  Kinda got sidetracked.  I am testing out FFImageLoading.  Repro sample is really difficult as it is not consistent at all.  I literally just took some of the images that get loaded a lot out altogether.  That has helped, but I still get the random error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this didn't fix my issue with MvxImageView, I tried Picasso.  I created a PicassoImageView object and created a public "ImageURL" that allowed me to still use the MvvmCross binding.  I haven't seen the error since.